# How to clean up the fasls using Slime?

Tags: common-lisp, code-cleanup, slime

In order to clean up fasls you can run on the Sly REPL the following command:

```
 (slynk-asdf:delete-system-fasls :package-name)
```

I am using Slime and SBCL. How would you achieve the same using SLIME?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-x slime-delete-system-fasls`

or

```
(swank:delete-system-fasls :package-name)
```

edit: a third way, from the REPL, is to type a "comma" command: type `,` then `delete-system-fasls` (completion is available).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `M-x slime-delete-system-fasls` yesterday. Why not slime-repl-delete-system-fasls?

Comment: why '-repl-'? There is nothing 'repl' specific for such an GNU Emacs command.

Comment: @PedroDelfino I added a specific shortcut from the REPL: `,delete-system-fasls` (a comma opens for some commands).

Comment: @RainerJoswig, Helm shows 2 commands `slime-delete-system-fasls` and `slime-repl-delete-system-fasls` I was not aware of the difference between them.